# Finding Equality around Axis of Symmetry

Tags: functions, transformation, symmetry

I have a particular function that for even numbers $m$ obeys the following equation:

$$f_{m,n}\left(\frac{2}{m}-x\right)=(-1)^nf_{m,n}(x)$$

Now when I put in odd values for $m$ and plot the function, they are not equal, but there appears to be a reflectional symmetry along the vertical line $x=\frac{1}{m}$. I am having trouble with the appropriate transformation of reflectional symmetry along an axis different than the $y$-axis.  I'm thinking it would be $x\mapsto{-(x-1/m)}$.  Is this correct?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reflect across $x = k$, just translate this line to go through the origin, reflect across the $y$-axis, and then translate back:

$$x \longmapsto x - k \longmapsto -(x - k) \longmapsto -(x - k) + k = 2k - x.$$

So you're right about an axis of symmetry $x = \frac{1}{m}$, but your functional equation actually spells out the transformation $x \mapsto \frac{2}{m} - x$ when $n$ is even.

You'll have rotational symmetry about $\left(\frac{1}{m}, 0\right)$ when $n$ is odd.

Comment: I noticed the odd even $n$ thing too just through observation.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: how would i make the rotational symmetry happen?  Same thing, but then make the function negative since for rotational symmetry we have $(x,y)\mapsto (-x,-y)$?

Comment: That sounds right, yes. I believe that functional equation is again spot-on. But yeah, the $x$-coordinate is transformed the same way in either case, but with a rotation, $y \mapsto -y$ as well.